# In java I how do I escape a * character

Tags: java, regex

I have a string

```
String a = "dcvdk*vmfdkvm*bmkjfnb*";
```

I want to replace the * character by space

```
I tried a.replaceAll("\*", " ");
```

But it is giving error as invalid escape sequence.
Can you please tell me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the escape character:

```
"\\*"
```

Alternatively, just use `replace`, which treats the arguments as literals, not regexes:

```
a.replace("*", " ")
```

Or, as [Aniket Sahrawat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6099347/aniket-sahrawat) points out, you can use the `char` overload in this case:

```
a.replace('*', ' ')
```

Comment: Or you can use `a.replace('*', ' ');` Any +1 for me? @Someprogrammerdude :p

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the backslash have a special meaning in strings, and you need to escape the backslash itself to get an actual backslash:

```
a.replaceAll("\\*", " ");
```